# Is it possible to apply reaction progress kinetic analysis on non catalytic reactions?

Tags: kinetics

I was wondering if anyone familiar with [reaction progress kinetic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_progress_kinetic_analysis) knows if it is possible to apply the method on non catalytic reactions, and if so provide a few references with relevant examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the method works normally with non catalytic reactions according to the example presented in a Mettler Toledo webinar (Titled: Reaction Progress Kinetic Analysis, https://www.mt.com/us/en/home/library/on-demand-webinars/automated-reactors/kinetic.html) where a simple Diels-Alder reaction is analyzed by RPKA.